# Is there anyway to turn off "show history" task in Eclipse Subversion when not connected?

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, subversive

I'm working on a project a work that runs on an intranet not connected to the internet. This intranet is also not connected to our SVN server. However I am able to use the same workspace as a machine that is connected to the SVN server. (Currently through NFS mounts). When I'm running on the machine that is unable to connect to the SVN, I keep getting "show history" tasks running that eventually show the following error box:

[image: Screen shot of error message in Eclipse]

Regardless of whether I hit "Yes" or "No" the dialog will come back over and over again. This seems to happen every time I save/compile.

This is happening on Eclipse version: Helios Service Release 2, build ID 20110218-0911

With Subversive SVN Team Provider version 0.7.9.120110207-1700 (org.eclipse.team.svn.feature.group).

I realize that I may have to upgrade either Eclipse or SVN. However this may be difficult, given corporate policy. If there is no other option, I can present this and maybe they'll let us upgrade.

Answer (score -1):

You are using Subversive, not Subclipse, so should probably change your tags.

The History view typically has an option to link it to the editor or view selection.  When this is turned on, the History view auto-refreshes every time you click on an item in your view or open an editor.  Turn this option off and it should resolve the problem.

Comment: I just updated the tags. Thanks for pointing out that I was using Subversive. I'll give it a try tomorrow and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: That doesn't seem to make a difference. I turned that off and now it submits 4 Show History tasks everytime I save. (It may be when Eclipse compiles)